# python join the last two indices in a list

Tags: python, list, join, indexing

i hope my question makes sense. i am looking to join the last 2 indices if an `IF` statement proves true but i am getting an error.

here is my text file:

```
AAA BBB CCC NY 10018      111111111E
AAA BBB CCC DDD NY 11946222222222E
AAA BBB CCC NY 10018      333333333E
AAA BBB CCC DDD NY 11946444444444E
```

here is my code:

```
with open('O:/python1docs/sample_1.txt', 'rb') as infile:

    data1 = []
    for row in infile:
        row = row.strip().split()
        rend = len(row) - 1
        rend2 = rend - 1
        rend3 = rend2 - 1
        if len(row[rend]) == 10 and len(row[rend2]) == 5 and len(row[rend3]) == 2:
            row = row[0:rend2] + ' ' + ''.join(row[rend2] + row[rend])
            data1.append(row)
        else:
            data1.append(' '.join(row))
    print '\n'.join(data1)
```

error message i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "O:\python1\py_programs\lipa_newbiz3.py", line 12, in <module>
    row = row[0:rend2] + ' ' + ''.join(row[rend2] + row[rend])
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

i can join any single index ie: `row = row[*] + ' ' + ''.join(row[rend2] + row[rend])`and the code works, but when i try to join all the indices together `row[0:rend2] + ' ' + ''.join(row[rend2] + row[rend])` it errors out

any help is greatly appreciated. -thanks

this is what i wanted

```
['AAA BBB CCC NY 10018111111111E']
['AAA BBB CCC DDD NY 11946222222222E']
['AAA BBB CCC NY 10018333333333E']
['AAA BBB CCC DDD NY 11946444444444E']
```

longer way

```
for row in infile:
    row = row.strip().split()
    rend = len(row) - 1
    rend2 = rend - 1
    rend3 = rend2 - 1
    row1 = []
    templist1 = []
    templist2 = []
    templist3 = []
    templist4 = []
    templist5 = []
    if len(row[rend]) == 10 and len(row[rend2]) == 5 and len(row[rend3]) == 2:
        templist1.append(' '.join(row[0:rend2]))
        templist2.append(row[rend2])
        templist3.append(row[rend])
        templist4.append(' '.join(templist1 + templist2))
        templist5.append(''.join(templist4 + templist3))
        print ' '.join(templist5)
    else:
        row = ' '.join(row)
        print row
```

here is a shorter way

```
for row in infile:
    row = row.strip().split()
    rend = len(row) - 1
    rend2 = rend - 1
    rend3 = rend2 - 1
    if len(row[rend]) == 10 and len(row[rend2]) == 5 and len(row[rend3]) == 2:
        row = ' '.join(row[0:rend2]) + ' ' + ''.join(row[rend2] + row[rend])
        print row
    else:
        row = ' '.join(row)
        print row
```

Comment: `row[*]` is `String` but `row[0:rend2]` may be `List`. So you concatenate "String" to "List" in `row = row[0:rend2] + ' ' + ''.join(row[rend2] + row[rend])`. This is the cause of this error.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you show exactly what result you want, for the given input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not apply '+' operator to string and list types

```
row = ' '.join(row[0:rend2]) + ' ' + ''.join(row[rend2] + row[rend])
```

or

```
tmplist = row[0:rend2]
row = ' '.join(tmplist.append(''.join(row[rend2] + row[rend])))
```